# Kinetic 22.10 - boot stuck on "device /dev/sda2: clean" message

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.10

Update - answers to questions below:

- System: Dell Inspiron 3668
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- Secure Boot is not active. (I checked)
- Using liquorix kernel.
- Disk has ~400GB free.
- output of `dkms status`:

  ```
  $ dkms status                                                                                                                                                         
  07:48:08
  virtualbox/6.1.38, 5.19.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox/6.1.38, 6.0.0-11.2-liquorix-amd64, x86_64: installed
  virtualbox/6.1.38, 6.0.0-9.1-liquorix-amd64, x86_64: installed
  ```

---

New update:

I was able to get my system to boot with the nvidia-drivers-515 package, just not the nvidia-drivers-525 one. 3d acceleration doesn't work.

I tried using a 5.19.0 kernel I had on my system, and with the nvidia drivers, it worked fine. I removed liquorix and installed "ubuntu mainline" 6.0 kernel, and that didn't work. But 5.19.0 does. So there's something with the 6.0+ kernels that doesn't play nicely with nvidia driver 525, at least on my system.

---

Original post below:

I did a package update, and rebooted my computer. From that point forward, it doesn't boot. I found previous suggestions here for solutions, but none have worked, and it was enough for me to just ask a new question. Things I have tried:

---

### Attempt #1:

1. Got into recovery mode
2. Dropped to a root shell
3. Ran `apt purge nvidia* -y ; apt autoremove --purge -y ; apt clean`
4. Ran `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
5. Rebooted with no success.

---

### Attempt #2

I tried steps 1-3 above, rebooted, and could get in without the nvidia drivers installed. *however, Ubuntu seems to correct this oversight on my end, and automatically reinstalls the drivers so on the next boot they exist and I am stuck*. This also prevents me from using my video card's 3d acceleration at all.

---

### Attempt #3

I tried steps 1-3 above. I removed the ppa for graphics-drivers, did a apt update, and then did steps 4-5. No change in result.

---

### Attempt #4

I tried steps 1-3 above, I then used `ubuntu-drivers devices`, found the correct package (525) and then tried just manually installing this directly, and this didn't do anything.

---

### Attempt #5

Like Attempt #4, but I tried different versions (510, 490, etc), to no effect.

---

I am stuck, and am really hoping someone can help me figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: I should note - I have an nvidia GPU. My system is a desktop, not a laptop. And before I did the initial package update and reboot that started this mess, my computer had been working flawlessly for a couple years.

Comment: You should not need ppa anymore, Ubuntu has nVidia drivers in its repository. Looks like you are doing correct steps. What brand/model system or motherboard. What nVidia card?  Post in question above. Did an UEFI update revert settings to defaults & you have Secure Boot on?

Comment: Updated the question with answers for you. I hope its enough.

Comment: There's no mention about you re-checking the UEFI settings and making sure Secure Boot is disabled?

Comment: Is your disk completely full ? please check you have some free disk space.

Comment: @ChanganAuto - I did check, it was still disabled.

Comment: @UtkarshChandraSrivastava - ~400GB free.

Comment: If I remove nvidia drivers, system will boot as normal, other than having any of my 3d acceleration of course. But then after I boot it, Ubuntu automatically will reinstall the nvidia drivers, so after I reboot again, I will be stuck.

Comment: I have not seen a system auto install drivers. Are you sure purge has run correctly and you are not just one time booting recovery mode that uses nomodeset as default. After boot of recovery mode, what does this show? `dkms status`

Comment: I would do the steps to uninstall the drivers, reboot without recovery mode, get in (both of my monitors work), and then I would check `ubuntu-drivers devices` or the GUI "Additional Drivers" and it would show nvidia 525 is installed. I reboot and it gets stuck. Then I have to reboot into recovery mode to be able to get into the system, to uninstall the nvidia drivers again.

Comment: So it seems to be something in the 525 driver that is the issue. I wish I could provide more information, but I just don't know what I don't know. any driver less than 525 will not do 3d acceleration.

Comment: Apparently, Kernels 6.0+ don't work with nvidia-drivers-525 for me. There's something in those. When I use a 5.19 kernel, things work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was using the stock Ubuntu Linux kernel 5.19.0-26-generic. This let me be able to use nvidia-driver-525 without problems.

I am hoping for a better solution, because I would rather be using a newer kernel.